# Workflow gives "Error Occured" when uploading file to document library

Tags: development, workflow, item

I am mapping one xml document to another. When it is done, I am uploading that document to a document library. Here is the code that does that:

```
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings();
            xws.OmitXmlDeclaration = false;
            xws.Indent = true;

            using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(ms, xws))
            {
                outputDocumentInfo.Xdoc.WriteTo(xw);
            }

            SPFolder mylibrary = web.Folders[siteCollectionInfo.DocumentLibraryName];

            // Set AllowUnsafeUpdates = true to avoid security error
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

            mylibrary.Files.Add(outputDocumentInfo.FileName + ".xml", ms, true);                

            mylibrary.Update();

            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

When the file is done uploading, it is valid and well formed xml. I can open it, submit, edit it, everything, but the status of the workflow says "Error Occurred" and the workflow will not start for that item. Under workflow settings I have made sure that " Start this workflow when a new item is created" is checked.

Anyone know what might be causing this?

Edit: When I download that same xml file and re-upload it (without making any changes) using the Upload Document button inside the document library, the workflow will start just fine.

Comment: Try to check sharepoint log file (**14/LOGS** folder). I think that it should has detailed information about the exeption.

Comment: Or try to debug the workflow using VS to get detailed error, cause current description it almost impossible to understand the reason of failure.

Answer (score 1):

do not use 
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
inside the workflow code instead use

```
using (spWeb web= workflowProperties.web)
{
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

}
```

this will resolve yor issue